# Google API Python Client - AccessTokenRefreshError

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth

```
def get_code(request):
    try:
        user_info_service = get_service(request.user, 'oauth2', 'v2')
        user_info = user_info_service.userinfo().get().execute()
        if user_info and user_info.get('id'):
            request.session['cur_user'] = user_info
            return redirect('/me')
        else:
            raise NoUserIdException()
    except AccessTokenRefreshError as atrfsh:
        print atrfsh
        print traceback.print_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
    except:
        print "This was the exception..."
        print sys.exc_info()
        auth_uri = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
        print auth_uri
        return redirect(auth_uri)

def get_service(user, name, version):
    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get()
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credential.authorize(http)
    service = build(name, version, http=http)
    return service
```

I keep getting an `AccessTokenRefreshError` on the `user_info = user_info_service.userinfo()`.. line.

In the except block for AccessTokenRefreshError, it's printing 'invalid_grant'.

Upon reading the documentation for `OAuth2Credentials` object: http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials-class.html#authorize, I found that the credential.authorize method in `get_service` apparently should automatically perform a refresh of the access token.

What am I doing wrong that it's not able to refresh the access token?

Answer (score 3):

**This is a workaround!**

I have also been getting the same error approximately once every 10 calls to `tasklists.list()`, so the problem is not unique to `userinfo`.

The only solution that I've found is to put the API call in a retry loop. Doing an immediate retry fails, so I include a sleep before retrying. With a 45 second sleep, it works approximately 99.5% of the time.

I hope that someone can post a better solution.