# AccessTokenRefreshError : Gdata Spreadsheet API with Service Account

Tags: google-oauth, gdata, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client, google-apps-marketplace

First some background, [Using Service Accounts with GData Spreadsheet API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20209178/492561) for an app installed via Google Apps Marketplace.

```
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
                    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
                    PRIVATE_KEY,
                    scope = SCOPE,
                    sub = "admin@domain.com")
    auth2token = gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
    client = SpreadsheetsClient()
    auth2token.authorize(client)
    q = SpreadsheetQuery(title= "ItemMaster",title_exact=True,)
    feed = client.get_spreadsheets(query = q)
```

The problem is that the API calls fail randomly with,

```
AccessTokenRefreshError: Invalid response 403.
Failed to retrieve access token: You are not authorized to perform this request.
```

I tried doing a test in which 10 API calls are made one after another with 1 second intervals between them, atleast 4 API calls failed with the above error.

I tried checked the quota on API console and that is not being exceeded, Per user limits on the API are at 100 requests/user/second for the Drive API, and billing is enabled.

PS: This question is different from [Getting AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant in Google API fro service account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18347959/492561) and [Google API Python Client - AccessTokenRefreshError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13982533/492561) which are related to `invalid_grant` while my issue is specifically related to Random Failures of API calls

EDIT: The problem seems to be related to [#210](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=210) in google-api-python-client

Comment: Is this using a refresh token to get a new access token? .... Anyway, I used the Google DrEdit example to code OAuth2, it worked, although needed to add a call to get the access token from the refresh token, as it expires after one hour. But it all works, never seen this issue.

Comment: @eddyparkinson Did you use service accounts and spreadsheet API ?

Comment: I use GData style "Spreadsheet API" and normal OAuth2 but have also used an API key. Looks like google have changed things, an "API key", looks different to a "service account". An API key also required an email address, so it looks a bit like your code above.

Comment: I think I found the issue, [#210](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=210) on google-api-python-client. 
We are facing a something very similar

Comment: Eventually, I've found the solution to your issue here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26931576/1549523
However, in my case the pattern didn't work with an impersonated user, i.e. the `sub` parameter.